# Losing connection to SQL Server on the same machine?

Tags: wifi, sql-server-2008-r2, networking

I've installed our SQL Server driven software on a client's computer. This consists of SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, and using ADO/SQLOLEDB drivers on a brand new Windows 8 64bit machine.

The problem is periodically the application's connection to the database randomly drops. Even if two different apps are opened and connected to the same database, they both lose connection at the same time. But yet, the SQL Server is on the same machine, so I don't understand how the connection could be dropping at all.

In the SQL Server configuration, I've enabled Named Pipes and TCP/IP, and set a fixed non-standard port for the TCP/IP. SQL Browser is disabled, so we connect via the port number, for example `MachineName, 12345` is the server address.

I also noticed a pattern - I'm using TeamViewer to connect to our client. Whenever I see the database connection drop, I also briefly lose my remote connection to their screen. So something fishy is going on in this machine.

It's a brand new machine out of the box, updates installed. It's also connected to WiFi, but yet, regardless of whether it even has a network connection, applications shouldn't be failing to maintain a steady connection to SQL Server on the same machine.

What could be causing this? We have many clients using this software in very large networks, and this is the first time I've seen this issue.

**UPDATE**

This client reported that they noticed a pattern in these drop-outs. It appears to happen every half hour, like clockwork. It's clear that there is something running on this machine which causes a brief break every 30 minutes. But what could it be? The computer is fresh out of the box, the only thing done with it is Windows Updates, SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, and our software, which certainly does nothing along these lines.

Comment: It's been a long time since I dealt with a similar problem. IIRC, SQL server has a "connection precedence" when multiple protocols are enabled (TCP/IP, Named Pipes, Shared Memory). If the application is using TCP/IP or Named Pipes then those are indeed network protocols and if the machine loses it's network connection that might explain the connection loss, regardless of whether or not the application and SQL are on the same machine. Try disabling TCP/IP and Named Pipes to force the application to use Shared Memory and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: @joeqwerty I will certainly test this to see if it makes a difference, however I will need these enabled because other client machines will be connecting into the server. Client connections I understand I cannot guarantee a steady connection, but this is the first time I've ever had issues with connections on the same machine.

Comment: Have a look in the system and application event logs to see if anything is logged at the same time as the disconnections.

Comment: I also have my suspicion that it may be some sort of antivirus / antimalware / firewall resetting the adapter possibly. I have yet to connect back with this client of ours to debug this issue.